# SEO impact of redirecting pages for individual properties to pages that each list multiple properties

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, content, page

I just wanted to ask a question about a situation we have in job. We have Property pages that are e.g 3 bedroom, four bedroom these are on separate pages so they have a unique name but also there is a site page which would have a list of the properties belonging to this, the problem we have is that we are getting duplicate content for the property pages as the body text is identical for each one as it is coming from the parent site.

My question is if we just have one page which would be the site and any traffic coming to the Property pages is redirected to the site page.  Would this impact the our SEO if we done this? The site would have the same content as the property pages. I hope this makes sense ?

Comment: Sorry I hope the question is clear?

Comment: Is your question about what will be the SEO impact as you will have similar content in listing page and dedicated pages (3,4 bedrooms etc)?

Comment: Is a "site page" like a category page that has listings of multiple properties?   If so, can you limit the amount of text that appears for each property?

Answer (score 1):

> if we just have one page which would be the site and any traffic coming to the Property pages is redirected to the site page. Would this impact the our SEO if we done this?

I'd say yes negatively.

Going by your description, it seems that you want to merge details of every property all onto one page. If you only have one or two properties to talk about, this might not be a big deal but since you're working for a business, I bet you're dealing with alot more properties. If they all go on the same page, then users will have a hard time finding the information they need since they will have to do lots of scrolling (and/or use the find text feature in their web browser). People want information quickly.

What I would suggest is to categorize your properties and if the category listings can fit without the need to scroll down much, then put the categories on the home page then under each category, you can list all the properties if there are only a few per category.

If there are hundreds of properties in a category and you want to display them on a page, then what you do is turn that page into a sub-category page and place the properties in the applicable sub-categories.

An advantage to categorizing things is that Google will see this and index the pages accordingly and when people search for the categories on Google, they can find the pages on your site without scrolling on your site endlessly.